# Getting"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" on Google Places API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently upgrading my website with Google Place API and I have one more problem away until I'm getting it to work and I don't understand why I'm getting this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`. I have readed the whole [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) and even "scanned" the whole [example file](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) but my code is the exactly the same as theirs.

Here's my code:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var myplace = '<?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", utf8_encode($_COOKIE["wrn-myplace"])); ?>';
var myplace_clean = '<?php echo $_COOKIE["wrn-myplace"]; ?>';

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'address' : myplace_clean}, function(results, status) {
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var myplace_center = results[0].geometry.location;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        var myplaceControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var myplaceControl = new MyPlaceControl(myplaceControlDiv, map, myplace_center);

        myplaceControlDiv.index = 2;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(myplaceControlDiv);
    } else {
        alert('Funktionen "geocoder" kunde inte användas på grund av följande fel: ' + status);
    }
});

var mapOptions = {
    streetViewControl: false,

    mapTypeControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },

    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};



map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('weather-map'), mapOptions
);


var input = document.getElementById('google-search');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if(place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);
    }
});


var cloudControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var cloudControl = new CloudControl(cloudControlDiv, map);

cloudControlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(cloudControlDiv);


var fullscreenControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var fullscreenControl = new FullscreenControl(fullscreenControlDiv, map);

fullscreenControlDiv.index = 3;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(fullscreenControlDiv);


var boxText = document.createElement("div");
boxText.style.cssText = 'background-color: #000000; border: 1px solid #ffffff; color: #eaeaea; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;';
boxText.innerHTML = 'Du är här';

var myPopup = {
        content: boxText,
        disableAutoPan: false,
        maxWidth: 300,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-100, -100),
        zIndex: null,
        boxStyle: {
            opacity: 0.80,
            width: '200px'
        },
        closeBoxMargin: '3px',
        closeBoxURL: 'http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/icons/search/fugue/icons/cross-octagon-frame.png',
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        isHidden: false,
        enableEventPropagation: true
};


var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
cloudLayer.setMap(map);

elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', getElevation);

map.setZoom(10);

$('#weather-data').load('jquery-fetch/fetch-weatherdata.php?place=' + myplace);
```

`show_position` is called in the `initialize` function and this is the "description" for my error message:

```
kK
tK.(anonymous function).dl
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:9
bf.(anonymous function).Hc.c%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:24
O%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:9
df%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:24
hf%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:24
(anonymous function)
ef.controls
(anonymous function)%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:24
b%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:10
bf.(anonymous function).Hc%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:24
O%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:9
bf.(anonymous function).Hc%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:24
af.(anonymous function).ke%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:23
bf.(anonymous function).Hc%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:24
ff%7Bmain,places,weather%7D.js:24
(anonymous function)
```

I'm calling for the JS file from Google like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={my API key}&sensor=false&libraries=weather,places"></script>
```

How can I fix my small problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is now solved. Apparently it was mandatory to have the text field within the DIV tags.

Comment: Can you please update your answer for benefit of others

Answer (score 5):

Got the same error. Turned out the element whose id Places was expected, didn't exist. Check for mistyped element ids, or copy/pasted code.

Answer (score -1):

Got same error. I had turned out to be because I had was calling initAutocomplete for the same address fields, twice. Once I removed the redundant request, it worked without error.

Comment: please ask questions in the comment  section